# how to change the size of the first icon tab only flutter

Tags: flutter, tabs, tabbar

```dart
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2.0),
              insets: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:10.0)),
              tabs: [
            Container(child: Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt,))),**how to decrese the size of this tab **
            Container(child: Tab(icon: Text("CHATS"))),
            Container(child: Tab(icon: Text("STATUS"))),
            Container(child: Tab(icon: Text("CALLS"))),
          ]),
```

Answer (score 0):

set `isScrollable` to `true` in the `TabBar`

```dart
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          isScrollable: true,
          indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
            borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2.0),
            insets: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:10.0),),
          tabs: [
            Container(child: Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt,))), // how to decrese the size of this tab **
            Container(child: Tab(icon: Text("CHATS"))),
            Container(child: Tab(icon: Text("STATUS"))),
            Container(child: Tab(icon: Text("CALLS"))),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```